# ConnectionRefusedError When Try to Load Dataset in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

i'm new in jupyter notebook. I'm trying to load dataset from url in jupyter. This is my code.

```
import pandas
url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00244/fertility_Diagnosis.txt"
names = ['season', 'age', 'childish-diseases', 'accident', 'surgical-intervention', 'high-fevers', 'alcohol-consumption', 'smoking-habit', 'hours-sitting-per-day', 'output']
dataset = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)
```

I've tried different link access but still got the same error.
I am getting the following error.

```
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1349             try:
-> 1350                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1351                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1239         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1240         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1241 

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1285             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1286         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1287 

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1234             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1235         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1236 

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1005         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1006         self.send(msg)
   1007 

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    945             if self.auto_open:
--> 946                 self.connect()
    947             else:

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in connect(self)
    916         """Connect to the host and port specified in __init__."""
--> 917         self.sock = self._create_connection(
    918             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    807         try:
--> 808             raise err
    809         finally:

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    795                 sock.bind(source_address)
--> 796             sock.connect(sa)
    797             # Break explicitly a reference cycle

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-38b195ec6fe4> in <module>
      4 url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00244/fertility_Diagnosis.txt"
      5 names = ['season', 'age', 'childish-diseases', 'accident', 'surgical-intervention', 'high-fevers', 'alcohol-consumption', 'smoking-habit', 'hours-sitting-per-day', 'output']
----> 6 dataset = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    428     # though mypy handling of conditional imports is difficult.
    429     # See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1297
--> 430     fp_or_buf, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer(
    431         filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
    432     )

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode)
    170 
    171     if isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, str) and is_url(filepath_or_buffer):
--> 172         req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)
    173         content_encoding = req.headers.get("Content-Encoding", None)
    174         if content_encoding == "gzip":

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
    139     import urllib.request
    140 
--> 141     return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
    142 
    143 

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    523 
    524         sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())
--> 525         response = self._open(req, data)
    526 
    527         # post-process response

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    540 
    541         protocol = req.type
--> 542         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    543                                   '_open', req)
    544         if result:

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_open(self, req)
   1377 
   1378     def http_open(self, req):
-> 1379         return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
   1380 
   1381     http_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

D:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1351                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1352             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1353                 raise URLError(err)
   1354             r = h.getresponse()
   1355         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

Note: the url of dataset is active and accessible, python version 3.8, anaconda version 3 (2020)

Can anyone tell me how to solve this? Thank you~